# Show that sequence converges in probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of iid. random variables with $\mathrm{Var}(X_1)<\infty$.

I want to show that $$nP((|X_1|\ge \varepsilon \sqrt{n})\rightarrow 0$$

My textbook provided a hint: $P((|X_1|\ge \varepsilon \sqrt{n})=P((|X_1|1_{|X_1|\ge \varepsilon \sqrt{n}}\ge \varepsilon \sqrt{n})$ where $1$ is just the indicator function. I could prove it by not using the hint, but I am curious how to do it with the hint, as I have no idea what to do with it.

In my proof I started with 
$$nP((|X_1|\ge \varepsilon \sqrt{n})=n\mathbb{E}[1_{|X_1|\ge \sqrt{n}\varepsilon}]$$ and then worked with $n1_{|X_1|\ge \sqrt{n}\varepsilon}$ as a function. I showed that it is dominated by a $L^1$ function which allowed me to show that the rhs. of the above equations converges to zero. Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear to me how you can dominate $n 1_{|X_1| \geq \varepsilon\sqrt{n}}$ by a $L^1$ random variable independent of $n$.

To use the hint, apply Markov's inequality to get
$$\begin{align*} P\left( |X_1| \geq \varepsilon \sqrt{n} \right) &= P\left(|X_1| 1_{|X_1| \geq \varepsilon \sqrt{n}} \geq \varepsilon \sqrt{n}\right) \\
&\leq \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2 n}\mathbb{E} \left[ X_1^2 1_{|X_1| \geq \varepsilon \sqrt{n}}\right].
\end{align*}$$
Now, since $X_1^2 1_{|X_1| \geq \varepsilon \sqrt{n}} \leq X_1^2 \in L^1$, we get that
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}\left[ X_1^2 1_{|X_1| \geq \varepsilon \sqrt{n}}\right] = 0$$
by the dominated convergence theorem. It follows that
$$0 \leq n P\left( |X_1| \geq \varepsilon \sqrt{n} \right) \leq \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}\mathbb{E} \left[ X_1^2 1_{|X_1| \geq \varepsilon \sqrt{n}}\right] \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0.$$